# Having trouble with interactive keyboard always bouncing- it is also bouncing the background of the collectionView

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an interactive keyboard with messages in it. It was nice and working well. All until I needed an image as the background. The way I set up the image was like this:

```
 let bgImage = UIImageView();
 bgImage.image = self.image
 self.collectionView.backgroundView = bgImage
```

The code for my keyboard scrolling and being interactive is this

```
 //(In viewdidload)  ....

self.collectionView.bounces = true
self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true //Scrolling
setupKeyboardObservers()
}
    func setupKeyboardObservers(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
}
  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func handleKeyboardDidShow(){
    if messages.count > 0{
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: messages.count-1, section: 0)
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

For some reason, this is also moving the background image of my collectionView which I guess makes sense. How could I work around this? I can't seem to find any other way of setting a background for collectionview without it moving:( 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Yes this will happen because you have added the image to the collection view background.
- Instead you should add it to the view first then add a collectionview on top of it and make collectionview background clear then it will not scroll the image.

Comment: I've tried this and for some reason when I make the collectionview background clear, it just doesn't show anything behind it but a black screen. I also can't scroll when I do this too.

Comment: are you using a collectionview controller or a uiviewcontroller?

Comment: Is it really impossible to do it with a UICollectionViewController? I'm having so many problems when I switched everything over. For example, the main one is how I have an interactive keyboard with a inputaccessoryview stuck to it, but the collectionview can't stick with it. And when I made it stick with it, basically back to this post's problem, where the background is just of the colectionview..