# How to have inputAccessoryView with both inputTextField and a UICollectionView following the keyboard in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I need to use a UIView for many reasons. The main reason being a weird and annoying glitch that made perfect sense actually. See my post: [Having trouble with interactive keyboard always bouncing- it is also bouncing the background of the collectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622871/having-trouble-with-interactive-keyboard-always-bouncing-it-is-also-bouncing-th/55626230?noredirect=1#comment97957179_55626230)

Here is a video of my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcxEJGqf7BE&feature=youtu.be

So what I have right now is in my viewDidLoad():

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 700)

    collectionview = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionview.dataSource = self
    collectionview.delegate = self
    collectionview.backgroundColor = .clear

    collectionview.register(ChatroomMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionview.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
    collectionview.bounces = true
    collectionview.alwaysBounceVertical = true //Scrolling
    collectionview.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollView.KeyboardDismissMode.interactive //Keyboard drop when scroll

    collectionview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left: 0, bottom: 8, right: 0)


}
```

And this is for what I have in the UIView that follows the keyboard.

```
 lazy var inputContainerView: UIView = {

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 700)

    containerView.backgroundColor = .white

    let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    sendButton.tintColor = .blue
    sendButton.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), for: .touchUpInside)
    containerView.addSubview(sendButton)
    //Add constraints x,y,w,h
    sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    sendButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    containerView.addSubview(self.inputTextField)
    //Add constraints x,y,w,h
    inputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    inputTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    inputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    containerView.addSubview(collectionview)

    collectionview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    collectionview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputTextField.topAnchor).isActive = true

    return containerView
}()

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get{
        return inputContainerView
    }
}
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

It is very glitchy though. The collectionview and inputtextfield do follow the keyboard easily when click up on the keyboard, but there is no interactiveness at ALL :( When I try to scroll down and have an interactive keyboard it just goes all the way down and does not even animate at all. Can anyone help please? I need to have this in a UIViewController too. Unless you are able to help me with my first post, then I will work around it with that way. I've been stuck on this for days now.

Honestly I don't even know what I am doing or if it is viable, but I just need to have a UIView with a inputtextfield following the keyboard, and also a UICollectionView following that inputtextfield. I need keyboard interactiveness too. This is what I have so far though.