# InputAccessoryView is going over navbar

Tags: ios, swift

So I am using a UIViewController. I have a inputaccessoryview which returns a UIView with a textField and a UICollectionView. 
(Also, if you're wondering why I'm doing this, it is because of my past problem that I am getting: [How to have inputAccessoryView with both inputTextField and a UICollectionView following the keyboard in a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661536/how-to-have-inputaccessoryview-with-both-inputtextfield-and-a-uicollectionview-f))

So right now I have the UICollectionView that is inside the UIView that is returned by inputaccessoryview going OVER the navbar.

This is a photo of what is happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0eGu.jpg

I think there was a similar question but it was for objC not in swift.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a top margin to the accessory view  ?

Comment: @pooja yes it isn't working